# Ayuda con el modulo sharp -Nodejs , express , multer

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, multer

Buenas tardes podrian ayudarme con mi modulo sharp  , el mismo no se ejecuta  y no logro entender  porque no funciona ... muchas gracias

```js
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.title = req.body.title;
    image.description = req.body.description;
    image.filename = req.file.filename;
    image.path = '/img/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    image.originalname = req.file.originalname;
    image.mimetype = req.file.mimetype;
    image.size = req.file.size;
    console.log(image.filename);
        sharp(image.filename)
            .resize(200,200).toFormat('jpeg')
            .toBuffer(function (err,info) {
    image.save();
    res.redirect('/');
    });
});

//e806de62-8e70-4449-9e27-acc48155c1b1.JPG
//la salida del console.log
```

Comment: Hola. Te da un error? Puede que esto te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54747298/4326551

Comment: Primero que nada .... **GRACIAS**  @Angel, por constestarme y ayudarme. Ha ce un mes empece con estos nuevos lenguajes y la verdad que no sabia donde colocar sharp en el codigo que es un tutorial de Fazt ( youtube )muy bueno ....   quiero redimencionar una imagen de 6mb a  una  thumb de 200 x 200 px , mi duda es  que uso una ruta  para recuperar los datos del form y subir la imageny los datos a mongodb ( yo pienso  que deberia tambiem en el mismo proceso redimensionar la foto

Comment: ... lo que me enviaste es para agregar una  nueva ruta  lo cual  , me confunde   si se pueden poner dos rutas post que afunten a "funciones distintas " o debo programar todo en un mismo bloque . gracias  elcodigo de @sharp pasa de largo sin hacer nada ... y no se que hago mal

Comment: Agrega estas dos lineas ` await image.save();  res.redirect('/');` dentro de el callback de ` toBuffer(function (err,info) {})`. Asi deberia funcionar. Lo ignora porque al parecer es asincrono.

Comment: router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.title = req.body.title;
    image.description = req.body.description;
    image.filename = req.file.filename;
    image.path = '/img/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    image.originalname = req.file.originalname;
    image.mimetype = req.file.mimetype;
    image.size = req.file.size;
        sharp(req.file.filename)
            .resize(200,200).toFormat('jpeg')
            .toBuffer(function (err,info) {
    image.save();
    res.redirect('/');
    });
});

Comment: @Angel ...si es correcto como me indicas , este codigo no ejecuta el sharp  si sube la imagen  correcta pero no la redimensiona , le quite el async / away  ( ya que daba error

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar este nuevo codigo. para entenderlo.

Comment: intento ... hoy empece con esto jajajjaja mil disculpas

Comment: ahi pude  editarlo

Comment: `req.file.filename` No esta vacio?  Ya lo comprobaste?

Comment: lo verifico ....

Comment: @Angel ahi lo comprobe

Comment: alguna idea angel @Angel

Comment: No estas subiendo ninguna imagen. Dame un momento para hacer un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal al parecer es que no estás recibiendo ninguna imagen. Para esto debes instalar primero `express-fileupload`.

```
npm i --save express-fileupload
```

Después necesitas poner un middleware que capture y ordene la imagen dentro de `req.files.miImagen`.

```
//Este ordena las imágenes para trabajar más fácilmente
app.use(fileUpload({debug: true}));
```

Esta ruta recibe la imagen, la procesa y la vuelve a mandar.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
//Esto es posible gracias a express-fileupload
let miImagen = req.files.miImagen;
//Tomamos solo la data por que es donde esta el buffer de la imagen. 
sharp(miImagen.data)
   //Aplicamos el tamaño.
  .resize(320, 240)
  //Convertimos de nuevo en imagen
  .toBuffer()
  //Y cuando todo esta listo recibimos el fichero.
  .then( fichero => {
    //Lo mandamos a donde queremos. En mi caso quiero que
    // lo dibuje en la respuesta
    res.write(fichero)
  })
  //Si hay errores al convertir la imagen aquí los captura. 
  .catch( err=> { res.write(err)})

})
```

Y esta es la plantilla html.

```
 <form action="/" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">>
  <input id="input-b1" name="miImagen" type="file">

  <input type="submit">
  <form>
```

Es muy importante recalcar que el `name="miImagen"` es el que vas a obtener
dentro de tu `req.files.miImagen`. También es muy necesario según la [documentación de `express-fileupload`](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload)  agregar en el form `encType="multipart/form-data"`

Esta es la documentacion de [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) y tambien te pongo el [ejemplo funcionando](https://repl.it/repls/CruelAnimatedCgibin).

> Cuando corras el ejemplo espera un poco a que instale sharp.

## IMPORTANTE

Con `multer` no hay mucha diferencia para la subida de ficheros solo que es mas poderoso a la hora de guardar los ficheros directamente.